# How to force WorkManager to do work when app is NOT running?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a work that I want to run immediately when app starts running. but I'm only using **Coroutines** for that.

After app is **killed** I want to schedule **WorkManager** to continue that work. Is that possible for WorkManager?

Note that I want app activity to be closed when I schedule the work with WorkManager.

Comment: Yes its possible with WorkManger

Comment: @Amitpandey ok. how?

Comment: Can you rephrase this? I don't understand what you mean. "I want app killed to continue work, not in background." It doesn't make sense to say Work Manager is doing work when the app is not running. The WorkManager task is part of your app, so if it's doing work, your app is running. Also, when you say the app is "killed", do you just mean the activity is closed, or when the OS terminates the whole application to save memory?

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks. I rephrased my question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Why does it matter if the activity is open or closed while you are scheduling work? And you didn't answer the question about the word "killed".

Comment: @Tenfour04 let me explain it this way: I have a coroutine scope bound to application (MainScope). I want when this scope stops working, schedule a work using WorkManager.